# Object Var or With Block not Set VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Im tyring to write a VBA code to Copy the active row to a new sheet. 
Then Pull up a user form with a text box entry and list entry.
When entered it will update the cells accordingly and update the date as well.

I am currently getting the Run-time error '91': Object varaible or with block variable not set. I can't Figure out where This error is coming from if you can help and explain it to me I would appreciate it greatly!

There are two files  one to call the userform which is where i am getting the error.

```
Sub NewCange()

 ChangeUserForm.Show


End Sub
```

and the userform code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


    Dim i As Integer, M As Integer, Result As Integer
    Dim N As String
    Dim MasterRange As Range, CopyRange As Range, NextRow As Range
    Dim ActiveRow As Long




  'Selects active row copies it and puts in empty row in the copy sheet


     ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row

            With Worksheets("Master")
                   .Activate
                   .Cells(ActiveRow, 1).Select
                   .Cells(ActiveRow, 1).EntireRow.Copy
            End With

            With Worksheets("Records")
                   .Activate
                   .Cells(ActiveRow, 1).Select
                Rows(ActiveRow).Select
        End With

         ActiveSheet.Paste      
Destination:=Worksheets("Records").Cells(ActiveRow, 1)



'Below here is the inserting new change into excel sheet




    Set MasterRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell)

     Worksheets("Master").Activate

    LocalListBox.Clear

'List of Locations for assets
With LocalListBox

    .AddItem "TB01 "
    .AddItem "TB02 "
    .AddItem "TB03 "
    .AddItem "TB04 "
    .AddItem "TB05 "
    .AddItem "TB06 "
    .AddItem "TB07 "
    .AddItem "TB07XP "
    .AddItem "TB08 "
    .AddItem "TB09 "
    .AddItem "TB10 "
    .AddItem "TB11 "
    .AddItem "TB12 "
    .AddItem "TB13 "
    .AddItem "TB14 "
    .AddItem "TB15 "
    .AddItem "TB16 "
    .AddItem "TB17 "
    .AddItem "TB17XP "
    .AddItem "TB18 "
    .AddItem "TB19 "
    .AddItem "TB20 "
    .AddItem "TB21 "
    .AddItem "TB23 "
    .AddItem "TB24 "
    .AddItem "TB25 "
    .AddItem "TB26 "
    .AddItem "TB27 "
    .AddItem "TB27XP "
    .AddItem "TB28 "
    .AddItem "TB29 "
    .AddItem "TB30 "
    .AddItem "TB31 "
    .AddItem "TB32 "
    .AddItem "CAB3 "
    .AddItem "CAB4 "
    .AddItem "CAB5 "
    .AddItem "CAB6 "
    .AddItem "CAB7 "
    .AddItem "CAB8 "
    .AddItem "CAB9 "
    .AddItem "CAB10 "
    .AddItem "CAB12 "
    .AddItem "CAB16 "
    .AddItem "CAB17 "
    .AddItem "CAB18 "
    .AddItem "CAB19 "
End With


   Set NameRange = ActiveCell

MasterRange = LocalListBox.Value
MasterRange.Offset(0, 2) = NameTextBox.Value
MasterRange.Offset(0, 1) = Date

Unload Me


End Sub
```

Comment: Rows(ActiveRow).Select missing period?

Comment: Do you know how to step through the code?

Comment: Yes but when I would step through it would go all the way through the user form then give me the error

Comment: Please refresh the page to see the answer

Answer (score 1):

> Run-time error '91': Object varaible or with block variable not set.

You are getting that error because you are trying to unload something which is just initializing.

So basically you can't do this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Remove `Unload Me` and put it in a button click. This way you will also let the user select a value from the listbox `LocalListBox` :)

In fact move this block of code in a Button Click

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MasterRange = LocalListBox.Value
    MasterRange.Offset(0, 2) = NameTextBox.Value
    MasterRange.Offset(0, 1) = Date

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

and declare `Dim MasterRange As Range` at the top of the userform instead in `UserForm_Initialize()`

Comment: Trying to use the selection made from the LocalListBox and put it into the 2nd cell in the active row. I tried changing it to what you had recommended but it didn't work. I just tried this as well and still was producing an error.

Comment: MasterRange.Offset(0, 1) = LocalListBox.Value
    MasterRange.Offset(0, 3) = NameTextBox.Value
    MasterRange.Offset(0, 2) = Date

Comment: sorry for the mess above i couldnt get the code in my edit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a period in a `With` statement:

```
With Worksheets("Records")
               .Activate
               .Cells(ActiveRow, 1).Select
            Rows(ActiveRow).Select
    End With
```

should be

```
   With Worksheets("Records")
           .Activate
           .Cells(ActiveRow, 1).Select
        .Rows(ActiveRow).Select
End With
```

Also, to find exactly where your error is, use F8 to "walk through" the macro.  Also, it is highly recommended to [avoid using `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) in VBA.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I realize it's not, like 2 seconds after your post though. :P  But he should still change it, because otherwise it's possible the macro will grab the wrong row.

Comment: That's ok.. Happens with me sometimes as well :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I did need to add that in either way